# Customize High Contrast Icon Theme in Ubuntu

Tags: themes, icons, customization

So I was messing around with the themes to make my Ubuntu better and I came through this icon pack called "High Contrast". I want to use this icon pack but it has some really bad icons on the navigation bar on top. How can I change this? Is it possible? Here is how my current PC looks like

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see the top left icon is bad and I want to change it. Any way on how to go about it?